# import quickfix with python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, quickfix

I would like to import quickfix with python 2.7.
However, it can not be installed with pip.
A lot of errors are displayed.

> Error sentence ↓
>
> Test_std_tr1_shared_ptr.cpp (1): fatal error C1083: Can not open
>   include file: 'tr1 / memory': No such file or directory
>
> Error C2065: 'shared_ptr': undeclared test_std_shared_ptr.cpp (5):
>   error C2062: type 'int' unexpected (5): error C2039: 'shared_ptr': is
>   not a member of test_std_shared_ptr.cpp ... not found
>
> C ++ \ Acceptor.cpp (21): fatal error C1083: Can not open include
>   file: 'stdafx.h': No such file or directory

Help me

Comment: I have little clue, as I don't work with Python and I don't know what PIP is, but both error messages say "Can not open include file" so it looks like whatever C++ version of QuickFix you've got isn't complete or compiled the way Python expects.

Comment: Check your include paths ?

Comment: ARE YOU USING MAC OR WINDOWS